# Show the Connect to a wifi UI on a Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, windows, networking, uwp

I am trying to show the Connect to wifi UI on my universal windows platform, mostly on windows IoT and on windows phone. I found this [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter.aspx), but it doesn't really show how can I show the UI for connecting to a wifi. How do make sure user connects to a wifi before he/she proceeds with the application.

Comment: On IoT, you are responsible for showing your own network UI. The [WiFiScan](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WiFiScan) sample shows you how.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, I found it out a little later about the WifiScan sample, I was wondering if there was a built in UI for IoT. Also if I want to perform the same on a windows phone (UWP) then how do I do it (something like the show phone call UI)?

Comment: [Here's the list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228342.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks :)